# how to update/delete rows in Bigquery from the python api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm designing a BigQuery job in python that updates and inserts into several tables. I thought of two ways to achieve that:

1. execute a query job and save the result into a temporary table with an update/insert indicator and process them after. But it's no clear how to update with python libraries.
2. load the whole data into a new partitioned table and skip updates/inserts. It takes a more space then I would like but partition expires in few days anyway.

Am I missing something? Is there other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19):

You can simply use [Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) instead of SQL queries when using the [Google BigQuery API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html).

For instance, in order to update specific rows in the following table:

```
Inventory
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
|      product      | quantity | supply_constrained |
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
| dishwasher        |       30 |               NULL |
| dryer             |       30 |               NULL |
| front load washer |       30 |               NULL |
| microwave         |       30 |               NULL |
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
```

you could use the following code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

dml_statement = (
    "UPDATE dataset.Inventory "
    "SET quantity = quantity - 10 "
    "WHERE product like '%washer%'")
query_job = client.query(dml_statement)  # API request
query_job.result()  # Waits for statement to finish
```

obtaining the following results:

```
Inventory
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
|      product      | quantity | supply_constrained |
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
| dishwasher        |       20 |               NULL |
| dryer             |       30 |               NULL |
| front load washer |       20 |               NULL |
| microwave         |       30 |               NULL |
+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Wow, that looks powerful

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to find among the many Google documents on the web, so worth to have it here, for reference. The information is [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/runtimeconfig/index.html).

And this is a minimal example that should be easy to adapt to any use case:

```
    import google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi as bq

    try:
        con = bq.connect()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        query = "<your sql command goes here>"
        cursor.execute(query)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
   except Exception as e:
        str(e)
```

Answer (score -3):

The method to update fields  in python is implemented in idiomatic library, it's called [update_table()](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.update_table). It calls into BigQuery API's [patch method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `update_table` is intended to update some fields (i.e. metadata) of the table, not the table content itself (i.e. rows) as asked by the OP. See documentation here:  https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_update_table

Comment: @DanielX2010 is correct. View this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-table-cmek